# Highest efficiency suub collection of sets.

Tags: combinatorics

Hy can some one help me to figure out this.

X is a set of type1 elements.
Y is a set of type2 elements.

Given a collection of sets (S) in which each set(Si) is a subset of XunionY. The efficiency of each set that are present in S is defined as the ratio of type1 and type2 elements in that.

The efficiency of sub collection is defined by the efficiency of the set formed by the union of all sets that are present in that Sub collection.

The problem is to find a sub collection who has highest efficiency. 
How I will proceed to this problem?

Comment: You defined the efficiency of a set.  How do you the efficiency of a collection of sets?

Comment: Is it seems to be right now?

Comment: How do you define the "efficiency" of a set if it contains NO elements of type2?

Comment: The efficiency of that type is defined as infinite(+).